# Can't pass data from child to child

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3

I have a parent and 2 children. I am trying to pass data from child1 to child2 but keep getting an error message: 1061: Call to a possibly undefined method through a reference with a static type.

In child1 I have the following code:

```
[Bindable]
public var TestVar:String='sometext';
```

In child2 I am trying to get the value of TestVar and then use it as a value to search a mysql database via php.:

```
  var newTestVar:String = child1.TestVar;
  if(newTestVar != null){
    getResult.token = someService.get_filtered_Paged(newTestVar);
  }

  else{
    getSecResult.token = someService.get_paged(); 
  }
```

Comment: Wehn you say parent / child, what do you mean ? child components of some container, or classes that inherit each other ? Also it would help to see how the child1 variable is declared (from the error message it could be that child1 is a actually the name of the class rather than an instance, but we cannot know unless you post more.)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

@ape is right, you should make is Static or use MVC to inject the property.

Answer (score -1):

change `public var TestVar:String='sometext';` to `public static var TestVar:String='sometext';`
You are getting this error because you are trying to access the variable: `TestVar` in a static context when you have not marked it static.

Answer (score -1):

You're getting this error because you declared child1 as a superclass of whatever child1 actually is. It's only natural that TestVar is not defined there. To top it off that superclass is not dynamic so you'd need to access that field with:

```
child1["TestVar"];
```

That will not generate a compile error, and should have no problem accessing the field at runtime if the instance held by child1 is the right one.

Answer (score -1):

Let's say you defined `TestVar` in MyClass1. Cast `child1` to that type:

```
var newTestVar:String = MyClass1(child1).TestVar;
```

If this does not help, please post bigger part of your code.